# Python Multi Threading not working properly

Tags: python, multithreading, class, object

I can't seem to get this Multi Threading code to work with my already structured Python script of a simple IP Pining script with a few other features.

After testing the Multi Threading code i though i was ready to implement onto my code, however i can't seem to be able to call a new thread correctly. I know this because if Multi Threading was working properly my GUI interface would not stop responding when the scanall() function gets executed upon pressing the Scan all IPs button on the GUI interface.

I'm also not getting anymore errors after finishing the implementation, so it's hard to know now what to proceed with. This extremely frustrating thank you for the help guys, i would love to tackle this one down!

This is the Multi Threading code:

```
    class ThreadManager:
    """Multi Threading manager"""
    def __init__(self):
        pass

    def start(self, threads):
        thread_refs = []
        for i in range(threads):
            t = MyThread(i)  # Thread(args=(1,))  # target=test(),
            t.daemon = True
            print('starting thread %i' % i)
            t.start()
        for t in thread_refs:
            t.join()


class MyThread(Thread):
    """Multi Threading"""
    def __init__(self, i):
        Thread.__init__(self)
        self.i = i

    def run(self):
        while True:
            print('thread # {}'.format(self.i))
            time.sleep(.25)
            break
```

And This is the code that executes the multi threading:

```
print("[Debug] Main Thread has been started")
self.manager = ThreadManager()
self.manager.start(1)
```

This is the Github for the entire script code and the Multi Threading implementation.

https://github.com/Hontiris1/IPPing

Comment: `thread_refs` is empty. you didn't append `t` to `thread_refs`

Comment: when i put any value inside of Threads_ref list it breaks the code.

Comment: what do you mean by breaks the code. as you see if the thread_refs is empty it will not wait for the threads to join ane will exit.

Comment: What would you exactly enter inside the Thread_ref list abhilb.

Comment: `thread_refs.append(t)`

Comment: So i added it to:         for t in thread_refs:
            thread_refs.append(t)
            t.join()

Comment: however it is still not working, no errors again and the same outcome as explained on the post.

Answer (score 0):

As you are not adding the value of `t` to `thread_refs` array. Its empty and is not waiting for the threads to join.

Change you `start` function like this:

```py
def start(self, threads):
    thread_refs = []
    for i in range(threads):
        t = MyThread(i)  # Thread(args=(1,))  # target=test(),
        t.daemon = True
        print('starting thread %i' % i)
        t.start()
        thread_refs.append(t)

    for t in thread_refs:
        t.join()
```

secondly you might want to remove the `break` statement from your `while` loop in the `run` function. Otherwise it will exit after printing `thread 0` once.

Comment: I've added the thread_refs.join(t) to my start function as you suggested, and got the following error from it.

Comment: AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'join'

Comment: sorry it was a typo. i meant `append`. updated the code

Comment: No errors just like when i added append before, however it's giving me my original problems with no errors. Thank you for the help :/

Comment: No, i mean that after adding what you've suggested i'm back to square one. I don't get any errors and my code/script behaves the same way. and it's a problem because what i also described on my original post its still happening.

Comment: I checked out your repo and after i make the changes I could see `[Running] python -u "d:\Projects\IPPing\main.py"
[Debug] Main Thread has been started
starting thread 0
hello from thread # 0`

Comment: But I am not sure what you wish to do in the thread run function ?

Comment: Yes, that's the output i would get from the start after i finished implementing into my code.

Comment: The problem is that the reason i added multi threading was because i didn't want my GUI to stop responding when using the scanall() function on ipfunc.py

Comment: I described in detail on my original post.

Comment: I understood that. My question is what you want to call in your thread run function. as of now, you are only printing hello

Comment: I want my scanlist() function on ipfunc.py to be handle inside that thread, so that my GUI interface can stop saying (Stop Responding) while the script waits for the Ping command results to end on the loop. This was the reason i implemented multi threading into the script.